# Embedding Readmore.js Plugin in Bootstrap Drupal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drupal, jquery-plugins, element

I cannot for the life of me get this to work -- I figured I'm doing something fairly silly -- I checked the site it's calling the correct plug (added to my .info file) but for whatever reason it simply does nothing.  I have it set to function on the article element which was what the developer was using.  Please if someone could explain why this isn't calling correctly.

```
<script src="/sites/all/themes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js?n45oaf/bootstrap/js/readmore.js"></script>
<script>
$('article').readmore();
</script>

<article class ="textwritten" style={height: 50px; overflow: hidden;}>
<a  class = "link" href= "/?q=node/11">
  <img class = "bordered_img" src="/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_tsunami/assets/tsusafety_icon.png">
  </img>
  <h1>Tsunami Safety Resources</h1>
</a>
<p>Lorem ipsum + more blabbity blah<p>
</article>
```

Comment: Is it because the style on the `<article>` is missing double-quotes?

Comment: That fixed a little issue I had with my styling but still has managed to call the js function. :(

Comment: Also, the Lorem Ipsum paragraph doesn't have a correct closing tag... Your example doesn't allow others to reproduce your problem - maybe you should create a new sample that others can use (i.e. reference .js files from the internet instead of from your webserver). Some things I would check: Is your js file correct (can you browse to it)? Also, does it have dependencies which you haven't included?

Answer (score 1):

Can't call Javascript inside drupal 7 directly.  Drupal 7 puts it inside a namespace.

Here is an example.

```
jQuery(function ($) { 
    // your jquery code here
});
```

Comment: This answer is fine as far as it goes, but it would be better to include a little more explanation--perhaps a link to the Drupal docs--so that future searchers can benefit from your question and answer.